# ¿Como puedo filtrar sin el nombre completo del archivos? (JavaScript-react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Me encuentro realizando un proyecto, en el cual consulto unos audios de mi local y tengo un filtro para acceder a las carpetas de dichos archivos y un input el cual cuando coloco el nombre completo del archivo con la extensión me trae el archivo de audio y lo monta en una etiqueta de tipo audio, lo que busco es que en el input con solo escribir parte del nombre del archivo lo traiga y haga el mismo proceso que mencione anteriormente, pero no se como hacerlo, tal vez si alguien sabe le agradecería la info, a continuación dejo mi código, gracias.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import fechas from "../elementos/fechas";
import Header from "../components/Header";

export default function HomeAdmin() {
  const [anio, setAnio] = useState("");
  const [mes, setMes] = useState("");
  const [dia, setDia] = useState("");
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState("");
  const [boton, setBoton] = useState(false);

  const clear = () => {
    setAnio("");
    setMes("");
    setDia("");
    setAudio("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />

      <div className="grid grid-cols-8 min-h-[95vh] bg-base-300">
        <div className="col-span-4 flex justify-center items-center">
          <div className="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-2xl">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title justify-center">Busqueda de audios</h2>
              <select
                className="select select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                value={anio}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setAnio(e.target.value);
                  setBoton(false);
                }}
              >
                <option selected>Año</option>
                {fechas.anio.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={index} value={item}>
                      {item}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
              <select
                className="select select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                value={mes}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setMes(e.target.value);
                  setBoton(false);
                }}
              >
                <option selected>Mes</option>
                {fechas.mes.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={index} value={item}>
                      {item}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
              <select
                className="select select-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                value={dia}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setDia(e.target.value);
                  setBoton(false);
                }}
              >
                <option selected>Día</option>
                {fechas.dia.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={index} value={item}>
                      {item}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </select>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="input input-bordered input-primary w-full max-w-xs"
                value={audio}
                placeholder="Nombre del audio"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setAudio(e.target.value);
                  setBoton(false);
                }}
              />
              <div className="card-actions justify-center my-3">
                {/* <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={() => clear()}
                >
                  Limpiar
                </button> */}
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={() => setBoton(true)}
                >
                  Buscar
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-4 flex justify-center items-center">
          {boton && (
            <div className="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-2xl">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h2 className="card-title">Audios</h2>
                <audio controls">                  
                  <source
                    src={`http://localhost/audios/${anio}/${mes}/${dia}/${audio}`}
                  ></source>                  
                </audio>    
               
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es ver las coincidencias de todos los audios y lo que ha escrito, deberias de tener en alguna variable la lista con todos los audios, por lo que solo quedaria comprobar si de todos hay 1 que coincida con la mayoria de caracteres de lo que ha escrito el usuario.

por ejemplo:

```
let escrito = "bad bunn"
const musicList = [
    "bad bunny",
    "marc antony",
    "toy story"
]

const matchMusic = musicList.filter(music => music.splice(0, escrito.length) == escrito)
    
if(matchMusic == 1){
        return matchMusic
}
```

En este caso mostraria badd bunny porque es el que mas coincide

Yo haria que te muestre la cancion solo si lo escrito coincide con solo un audio, ya si hay mas de uno ya decidiras si te lo apañas para mostrar todos los que coincida, que es practicamente igual que el codigo que mostre pero en la condicional en vez de verificar si es 1, verificar si es mas de 0.

Espero haber ayudado